# Pytests on web.py application not covering methods code

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, web.py, pytest-cov

First of all, sorry if the linguo is not 100% correct or something does not make 100% of sense, I am quite new into web aplication development and posting on stack overflow in general.

I have a web.py application and need to test its functionalities with pytest and generate a code coverage report with `pytest-cov`. I get the tests to work and assert on the responses, but when I generate the code report, all the lines of code inside the methods are uncovered and therefore get a really low test coverage (23%)

I am successfully running `pytest --cov` in my repository via cmd and getting the coverage result in it. But then I tried using `coverage run -m pytest test_Server.py` and running `coverage report` to get a bit more detail.

In this report is where I could see which lines of code I was missing, and I was missing all of them except the definition of each method/class.

Another thing I tried is `pytest --cov=Server.py`, which then gives me the error

```
Coverage.py warning: Module Server.py was never imported. (module-not-imported)
Coverage.py warning: No data was collected. (no-data-collected)
WARNING: Failed to generate report: No data to report.
```

Server.py

```
import os

import web


URLS = ("/", "Index")

APP = web.application(URLS, globals())


class Index:
    """
    Just a test echo server.
    """

    def POST(self):
        web.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        data = web.data()

        return data
```

test_Server.py

```
from paste.fixture import TestApp
import pytest
import os
import sys

sys.path.insert(1,(os.path.join(sys.path[0],'..'))) #adding parent path to import server script
import Server as lm
from Server import APP as app, Index

host = "localHost:9999"


class TestRig():
    def test_server_setup(self):
        middleware = []
        testApp = TestApp(app.wsgifunc(*middleware))
        try:
            r = testApp.post("http://%s/" %host)
            print ("request:", r.status)
            assert r.status ==  200

        except TypeError:
            print ("Request failed. Status:"+ r.status)
            raise
```

This is a very simplifyed version of what I am currently running, and one way or another I manage to get the tests working and assert the responses correctly.

What I would expect is for the code inside the methods to be covered with the tests, but the actual output tells me only the definition of the method is covered and nothing else.

Comment: You should pass `--cov=Server`. `--cov` accepts qualnames, not files. `--cov=Server.py` would mean "look for a package `Server` and inside it for a module `py` (file `py.py`)", which you obviously don't have.

Comment: Thanks for the correction! Tried what you suggested and I don't get the "No data to report" anymore. Still, the main problem persists: Code coverage is 23% and no code inside the methods in Server.py appear to be covered :/

Comment: Hmm, I've copied the code from your question and executed the test via `pytest --cov=Server`, coverage is at 100%. Had to add the `Content-Type` header to satisfy `paste`, though but it shouldn't be an issue. So there's no problem with the code you've posted - try reducing your app to a [mcve] an include the code in your question.

Comment: BTW `pytest-cov` can also generate reports, try e.g. `pytest --cov=Server --cov-report=term-missing --cov-report=html`, this will print coverage table in terminal and create HTML report file.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I actually got it running inside the methods and can see all the lines covered way better with the HTML report file :) My next step is trying to upload files for another method which needs a JSON... But that is not related to this issue anymore.

I don't know If I can vote your answer as correct one, but it definitely was. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @hoefling I figured out two things:

1. When using `Web.py`, you need to use `paste.fixture` library to test the code, `requests` library WON'T cover your code even though you can assert and use get/post methods (here is why I got such a bad code coverage in the beginning).
2. When using pytest-cov (or coverage.py), make the call as such: `pytest --cov=name_of_your_script_to_cover --cov-report=term-missing --cov-report=html` to avoid the `Failed to generate report: No data to report.` error (and additionally get a nice HTML report to view your code coverage).