# py-test coverage covers def, but not method

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytorch, pytest

I am successfully running pytest and getting coverage in my forked [PyTorch](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch) repository. However, in some of the files covered in the report, I am often getting coverage for the definition, but not the method.

I run this command:

`pytest test_indexing.py --cov-report html --cov=torch`

And in one of the files covered in the report I have:

[image: coverage report]

There is a stackoverflow post with a very similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56293883/pytests-on-web-py-application-not-covering-methods-code), but the mentioned `paste.fixture` library does not work for me.

How do I get the method to run? Any guidance / tips will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I guess the pytest output shows that the tests are correctly run?

Comment: This means the methods were imported, but never executed - check whether the tests actually call them.